# osm2po street IDs

Tags: openstreetmap, osm2po

Is it somehow possible to always get the same IDs in the _2po_4pgr table and in the routing graph when it's run on newer version on the map? So if I ran it on OSM from today, and then on the same area OSM file 6 months from now, is it possible for the street IDs that osm2po generates still be the same?

I'd imagine not because OSM might've added more streets (or changed them), but maybe there's some trick that can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs created by **osm2po** are rather technical pointers and actually change when osm-data or the configuration changes. **osm2po** also writes the underlying osm-ID which usually does not change (for a while). But there's no guarantee.